# How to use 'DISTINCT' in Codeigniter Active Records?

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have a query using active records.

```
$this->db->select('reg.users_id,reg.registration_id,reg.device_type');
$this->db->join('users as usr','usr.users_id = reg.users_id','left');
$this->db->where('usr.users_status',1);
$this->db->where('reg.users_id',91);
$query = $this->db->get('users_gcm_registration as reg');
```

I want to fetch `DISTINCT(registration_id)`.

How can I do that?

Comment: How did you get on with the answers below?

Comment: Downvoted, for ignoring the people who help you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use distinct as

```
$this->db->distinct('reg.registration_id');
$this->db->select('reg.users_id,reg.device_type');
....
```

But better use `group_by`

```
$this->db->select('reg.users_id,reg.registration_id,reg.device_type');
$this->db->join('users as usr','usr.users_id = reg.users_id','left');
$this->db->where('usr.users_status',1);
$this->db->where('reg.users_id',91);
$this->db->group_by('reg.registration_id');// add group_by
$query = $this->db->get('users_gcm_registration as reg');
```

Comment: `->group_by()` is definitely the way forwards. Remember that you can chain functions too. i.e: `$this->db->select('*')->where('result.whatever', '24');`

Comment: `distinct()` expects a boolean type value.  If you pass it anything that is not a boolean, the value will be disregarded and `true` will be used as the passed value.  Check the source code in your CI project... `public function distinct($val = TRUE) { $this->qb_distinct = is_bool($val) ? $val : TRUE; return $this; }`

Answer (score 3):

Just use `$this->db->distinct();` That's it. It will distinct the value...

Hope it works fine for you...

Answer (score 3):

You have two way to fullfil this

1. In Codeigniter way
2. In SQL way

---

**Codeigniter way**

You can use `$this->db->distinct()` in your active record query.

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->get('table_name');
...
```

**In SQL way**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_name ...");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   $query = $this->db->select('registration_id')
                ->distinct('registration_id')
                ->from('reg')
                ->get(); 
 return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('reg.users_id,DISTINCT(reg.registration_id),reg.device_type'); 
   $this->db->join('users as usr','usr.users_id = reg.users_id','left');
$this->db->where('usr.users_status',1);
$this->db->where('reg.users_id',91);
$query = $this->db->get('users_gcm_registration as reg');
```